# Создать зависимое свойство

Tags: c#, silverlight

Прочёл главу книги Мак-Дональда про зависимые свойства, но не удаётся использовать приведённые фрагменты кода. Не могли бы Вы привести простейший полноценный пример создания зависимого свойства ? Вот код, который приводится в статьях, но не ясно как его использовать для создания зависимого свойства:

```
public class FrameworkElement: UIElement
 {
public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginProperty;
...
 }
...
static FrameworkElement()
{
MarginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Margin",
typeof(Thickness), typeof(FrameworkElement), null);
...
}
...
public Thickness Margin
{
get { return (Thickness)GetValue(MarginProperty); }
set { SetValue(MarginProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Думаю было бы уместным упомянуть хотя бы язык на котором пишите и "приведённые фрагменты кода" которые "не удаётся использовать"

Comment: Вы имеете в виду dependency property? Полно примеров же в гугле. Напишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать, и какие ошибки происходят.

Comment: Пока у меня видимо недостаточно знаний для создания собственного контрола, но я бы хотел научиться создавать зависимые свойства (dependency property). Привёл пример кода из книг и статей и указал язык.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для начала, вам нужен класс (ваш собственный!), в котором будет определено DP. Этот класс должен быть потомком `DependencyObject`. Если вы определяете контрол, вам достаточно унаследоваться от любого UI-класса, например, `UserControl`. Пусть имя вашего класса `C`.
2. Затем, в классе `C` пишете такой код:

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(int), typeof(C));

   public int X
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(XProperty); }
       set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
   }
   ```

   (можно писать не руками, а воспользоваться сниппетом `propdp`). Таким образом вы определяете DP типа `int` с именем `X`. Если нужен другой тип или другое имя, подправьте во **всех** нужных местах. (Если подправить не везде, работать не будет. Наверное легче стереть старое DP и создать новое.)
3. Если что-то не работает, то вы что-то сделали неправильно. Должно работать.